# Ionic ion-back-button does not work correctly in iOS, Angular router problem

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, router

I use "Angular 8" with "Ionic 5" the ion-back-button does not work correctly, use:

import {Location} from "@ angular / common"
private location: Location,
  this.location.back ();

Location works perfectly on Android and Web but it doesn't work on iOS. Some alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Angular Router instead of `Location`. Here are the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router) and here are the [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation). Spend some time there familiarizing yourself with those concepts.

Then download the Ionic Conference starter app and explore that project to see how they implement routing. Run `ionic start "Conference App" https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app`

Armed with the theoretical understanding from the docs and the practical project from Ionic, you should be able to set up routing to work across web, Android and iOS.